# Безопасность хранения данных в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, безопасность, шифрование

Есть проект, используется NodeJS и MongoDB. Возникла потребность максимально обезопасить данные. Каким способом это возможно/лучше сделать?
Проблем может быть несколько:

1. Сервер взломали, но как не дать прав копировать базу без доп ключа или подобного?
2. Базу утащили. Как хранить её в зашифрованном виде, чтобы злоумышленник не смог ею воспользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Никак, получив полный доступ к серверу, **хакер скорее всего найдет доступ к вашему алгоритму шифрования или ключам**, которые вы используете для получения данных с зашифрованного сервера.

И кто сказал, что базу обязательно тащить через ssh или другой протокол с уязвимостями? Ее могут спокойно выкачать через метод в котором у вас есть **возможность исполнять код** в вашем приложении (уязвимость)

Безопасность данных **может быть нарушена в любом месте** и защищая только одну сторону вашего замка, другую обязательно сломают.

1. А надежный ли у Вас дата-центр?
2. Уверены ли Вы, что у вас жесткий диск с данными не украдут?
3. Уверены ли вы в безопасности своего приложения, которое имеет прямой доступ к данным?
4. Может есть другие приложения в которых есть уязвимости? Прежде всего защищен ли Ваш компьютер, который имеет доступ к серверу, от вирусов?

Основное правило заключается в том, что сервер с базой данных надо **располагать отдельно от других приложений** и разрешать к нему доступ только из внутренней сети. В самом приложении нужно проверять, что пользователь не имеет возможности выполнить какой-то свой код на базу данных и сервер на котором стоит приложение защищен от внешних атак, хотя бы от атак позволяющих получить **неконтролируемое удаленное исполнение программного кода** от root.

Конечно, вы можете развернуть свою базу данных в **криптоконтейнер**, зашифровать все через 50 ключей, поставить систему которая будет отслеживать подозрительные запросы и логины, но какая будет стоимость владения всем этим? Стоят ли эти данные тех расходов, которые у вас будут каждый месяц?

Может лучше **придерживаться основных правил** и забыть про параною что у вас данные всегда могут утащить и пытаться навешать решений, которые тянут за собой лишние расходы.